# How to drive the color in node editor by the color of the light?

Tags: node-editor, drivers

[image]
I want to control the color in the node editor by light color.

After trying it myself, I guess I should probably get the RNA properties and enter it in the driver editor in the correct way.

I searched for official manuals and tutorials for this, but I did not realize how to manipulate them.

Help me please.

Thank you in advance.